# Distorted vertical arrows

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

I had this problem before, but can't find anything about it on the web.

I will paste, what looks like a lot of code, but really it's not.
On the top are just some parameters: lengths of arrows, their thickness to length ratio, their colors. Most other code is just plotting those arrows.

```
Clear["Global`*"];

\[CurlyPhi]=30\[Degree];
\[Alpha]=55\[Degree];

RKr=1;   (*Krogle*)
LBaz=.6;
Lv0=.35;
L\[Omega]=.3;
Rkoti=.2;

DebFaktPu=.03;(*del dolžine*)
KonFaktPu=.07;

(*****************COLORS******************)
BKr={0,.8,1,.3};
{Bii,Bjj,Bkk}=IdentityMatrix@3;
Bv0={1,.6,0};
B\[Omega]={1,0,1,1};
NeProz\[Omega]2=.7;
Bkoti={0,0,0};
NeProzKotiNot=.6;
(****************************************)

VelNap=50;  (*napisov*)
res=500;
Gledišče={.7,-2,.6};



(*********************************************************************************)
(*********************************************************************************)
(*********************************************************************************)



r0=RKr{Cos@\[CurlyPhi],0,Sin@\[CurlyPhi]};
jjNor={0,1,0};
kkNor=Normalize@r0;
iiNor=jjNor\[Cross]kkNor;




(*********************************************************************************)
(*********************************************************************************)
(*********************************************************************************)




Show[
 
Graphics3D[{
    RGBColor[BKr],
    Sphere[{0,0,0},RKr]
}],
 
 (*RED ARROW*)
 Graphics3D[{
    RGBColor@Bii,
    Arrowheads[LBaz KonFaktPu],
    Arrow[
    Tube[{
        r0,r0+LBaz iiNor
    }, LBaz DebFaktPu]]
}],

(*GREEN ARROW*)
 Graphics3D[{
    RGBColor@Bjj,
    Arrowheads[LBaz KonFaktPu],
    Arrow[
    Tube[{
        r0,r0+LBaz jjNor
    }, LBaz DebFaktPu]]
}],

(*BLUE ARROW*)
 Graphics3D[{
    RGBColor@Bkk,
    Arrowheads[LBaz KonFaktPu],
    Arrow[
    Tube[{
        r0,r0+LBaz kkNor
    }, LBaz DebFaktPu]]
}],

(*MAGENTA ARROW*)
 Graphics3D[{
    RGBColor@B\[Omega],
    Arrowheads[L\[Omega] KonFaktPu],
    Arrow[
    Tube[{
        {0,0,RKr},{0,0,RKr+L\[Omega]}
    }, L\[Omega] DebFaktPu]]
}],

(*MAGENTA ARROW*)
 Graphics3D[{
    RGBColor@(B\[Omega]{1,1,1,NeProz\[Omega]2}),
    Arrowheads[L\[Omega] KonFaktPu],
    Arrow[
    Tube[{
        r0,r0+{0,0,L\[Omega]}
    }, L\[Omega] DebFaktPu]]
}],

(*ORANGE ARROW*)
 Graphics3D[{
    RGBColor@Bv0,
    Arrowheads[Lv0 KonFaktPu],
    Arrow[
    Tube[{
        r0,r0+Lv0 {Cos@\[Alpha],Sin@\[Alpha]} . {iiNor,kkNor}
    }, L\[Omega] DebFaktPu]]
}],
 
 
Boxed -> False,

ViewPoint->Gledišče,
ViewVertical->{0, 0, 1},
(*SphericalRegion\[Rule]Sphere[{0,0,0},1],*)
 

Background ->RGBColor[1+{0, 0, 0}],
Lighting -> "Neutral",
ImageSize -> res
]
```

[image]
As you can see other arrows are ploted normally, but the vertical (magenta) arrows are distorted.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: version 13.1 no such problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I just upgraded 13.0.1.0  ->  13.1, as @cvgmt suggested and the issue is gone:[image]

So it was probably just a bug fixed with the latest version.

What I also found out working for previous version is to just change arrow direction for an arbitury small amount from vertical.